# Ошибка при подключении postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Уточните, в чем может быть проблема. Пытаюсь через терминал подключится к psql.exe (указываю путь к файлу). Сначала , он требовал пароль к пользователю , но введённый мной он не принимал. Далее , я в файле pg_hba.conf изменил методы на trust и теперь если попытаться через терминал достучаться до psql.exe , он выдает ошибку : "psql: ошибка: не удалось подключиться к серверу: ВАЖНО:  роль "bangbrosy" не существует" bangbrosy - это имя компьютера.
Как можно задать роли ? Как проще обойти ошибку?
(ОС windows)

Comment: напишите команду, который вы "стучитесь до psql"

Answer (score 0):

у меня была такая ситуация. Я удалил postgres и установил заново и при установке важно указать пользователя и пароль на английском языке. Мне это помогло.